# EPiServer [ContentOutputCache] - Stop cache clear on Admin login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, episerver

Recently I implemented [ContentOutputCache] for one of our sites and for the most part it's great. The cache seems to stop working when an Admin logs on to the CMS. This is probably by design. Is it at all possible to stop this happening? I want the cache to refresh only when something is published.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand it, logged in administrators and editors will always see the NOT cached information. So when I want to test the cache I usually have two different browsers opened. In one I am logged in and in the other I'm not logged in. If you're logged in then you usually want to see the most up to date information and not the cached. But of course if another ordinary guest views the site at the same time as the editor/administrator, then the ordinary guest will still see the cached version (until an editor or an administrator saves some changes).

Comment: Thanks for the answer that makes sense :D

Answer (score 3):

The output cache is disabled if a user is authenticated and it's created this way for a very good reason and this behavior has not been made to be changed.

If this was not the case it could lead to unauthorized access to secured content. This would happen if the first visitor to load the resource was authenticated with access to it.
As the output cache works by bypassing the generation of the content, which is the whole point of it, it would also be impossible (very hard) to run authentication checks for each item that was used to generate that content.

Also, as @sam-m mentions, this doesn't affect how the cache is working for other unauthenticated visitors, which would lead me to take a step and question the reason for needing the output cache for administrators in the first place, especially considering that output cache is only intended to  improve performance under load.

Comment: Hi, you are right I wasn't looking for caching content for Admins. As I was testing this on my dev box I assumed that if an Admin logged in it stopped caching for all users authenticated and non authenticated. This makes sense now it's been explain thank you for your answer.